# Timezone issue when passing data contract to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime, timezone, datacontract

I have WPF application which communicates to my central server is using WCF.

I have many pages where I use date fields in add/edit forms.

On some forms, I face this weird & peculiar issue where if I select today's date and send data to WCF using a async call, it uses yesterday's date.
I am using "*telerik datepicker*" in my xaml file and I am binding a "*datetime*" field to it.

After spending days doing research on this using various tools (fiddler and SQL profiler), I came to know that this happens only when the input datetime field sent to WCF has timezone information (came to know after observing data captured in fiddler) and time is 00:00:00.

In fiddler, the value sent to WCF service is 2017-08-17T00:00:00+05:30.

When I debug application and see the datetime property in quick watch, it shows "DateTimeKind.Local" as the Kind.

When I use following code and send the date I was able to solve this using following code:

```
public async Task SaveMyData()
{
  //MyObject is instance of data contract.
  MyObject.CreatedOn = DateTime.SpecifyKind(_dataCreatedOn , DateTimeKind.Unspecified); //Without this line, the service will take yesterday's date.
  isSaved = await MyService.SaveData(MyObject, token);
}
```

I know this is not a good practice & will mostly use DateTimeOffset approach described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidrickard/2012/04/06/datetime-and-datetimeoffset-in-net-good-practices-and-common-pitfalls/).

Would appreciate any I can get any help to locate the root cause of the problem.

Comment: We don't really have enough information here. A [mcve] would really help, along with the values that you're seeing. (Making half the post bold does *not* help for readability though.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have modified my question accordingly. Please go through the same and let me know if you need any other details

Comment: There's no need to show a screenshot - it would be better if your post contained the value directly, along with the original "kind" and value, and your time zone.

Comment: @JonSkeet Info updated.

Comment: Right. So that seems like a fairly reasonable representation of a `DateTime.Local` value. I would suggest that the root cause is using a `DateTime.Local` value at all. Using either unspecified (if you're talking about a floating time) or UTC (if you're talking about a specific moment in time) seem reasonable. For something like "created on" I'd try to use a UTC timestamp rather than just a date, personally.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not using the DateTimeKind.Local explicitly, it is by default. Also, DateTime.Unspecified will solve the problem but I don't know what is the cause of this. The example I gave uses createdOn but the actual field can be SupplierGoodsRecievedDate or any other datetime.

Comment: "it is by default" - well where did the value come from? It will certainly be the default if you use `DateTime.Now`, but I'd suggest avoiding doing that. If you use `DateTime.UtcNow` for every timestamp in the system, you'll use UTC everywhere. If you use `new DateTime(year, month, day)` that will have a Kind of Unspecified too. You need to track down where these "local" values came from - *that's* the cause, and we can't find it for you.

Comment: @JonSkeet The property is binded to a telerik RadDateTimePicker in WPF. That is where the datetime value with kind as Local come from. I am checking if there is any way we can control this in datepicker. Meanwhile, if you have any idea related to this issue with WPF binding and telerik RadDateTimePicker, do let me know.

Comment: It sounds like the RadDateTimePicker is the whole problem, and you can remove the WCF part entirely, stating in your question that you want a way of making it provide Unspecified instead of Local values. Or you could just accept that RadDateTimePicker *is* the cause you're looking for, and use your workaround, which seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried removing the RadDateTimePicker and used the default dateTimePicker control of WPF but the problem still persists. So, I think the RadDateTimePicker is not really the problem. I am looking for a generic solution wherein I don't have to fix this at every service call used for saving data in db.

Comment: All that says is that both RadDateTimePicker and the default DateTimePicker may be giving you `Local` values. That doesn't mean they're not the cause. I really don't think there's anything more to find here: you should fix the kind to `Unspecified` for every value, because `Local` is basically problematic. I wouldn't do that at the *service* call - I'd do it as early as possible.